# C#: HttpClient POST pass parameters - one string and int array

Tags: c#, post, httpclient

I'm having some issues with calling an API. I need to send post data containing 2 things: an ID and an array of int. 
I have tried a lot of things, all resulting in errors or simply not sending data in the right way. All answers I found, do not handle the fact that I want to send 2 different data types.

On the other side I have:

```
Call<DefaultResponseList> someMethod(@Field("parm1") String parm1, @Field("parm2[]") ArrayList<Integer> parm2);
```

I tried:

```
List<int> ints1 = new List<int>();
ids.Add(1);
ids.Add(2);
ids.Add(3);

var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, object>("parm1", "lkdjfowejfd123"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, object>("parm2", ints1)

};

var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler());
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(someUrl, new FormUrlEncodedContent(values));
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

string data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: You should know `someUrl`'s environment and then arrange your values according to this information. Ex if target environment is a Apache/PHP server your keys should be like param2[], for classic ASP.NET envrionment values should have same key name with occurence, and if its ASP.NET MVC your key should contains indices like param2[0],param2[1] etc.

Comment: Target environment is a Apache/PHP server.

Answer (score 5):

I solved the problem.
Thanks to Cihan Uygun for his comments.

```
List<int> ids = new List<int>();
ids.Add(1);
ids.Add(2);
ids.Add(3);

var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("parm1", "lkdjfowejfd123")
};

int counter = 0;
foreach (int i in ids)
{
    values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("parm2[" + counter.ToString() + "]", i.ToString()));
    counter++;
}

var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler());
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(urlSaveRegions, new FormUrlEncodedContent(values));
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

string data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

Post an integer array using StringContext

```
var myData = new { myvar = "my string", data = new[] {1,2,3,4,5}};

var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler());

var jsonObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myData)
var stringContent = new StringContent(jsonObject.ToString(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(urlSaveRegions, stringContent);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

string data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```